# Print first word of first line and last word

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I'm trying to parse a log file in SHELL and want to print first word of first line and last word of each line under it.

For instance:

```
$ grep -A3 "2015-01-22T07" Test.log | grep -A3 "Messages from Summary report is"    
2015-01-22T07:36:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ Number of C is 1500
Total distance 10 km    
Total number of A is 2    
Number of B is 2
]
--
2015-01-22T07:37:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ Number of C is 1600    
Total distance 11 km    
Total number of A is 3    
Number of B is 3
]
--
2015-01-22T07:38:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ Number of C is 1700    
Total distance 12 km    
Total number of A is 4    
Number of B is 4    
]
```

Expected output:

```
2015-01-22T07:36:30,1500,10 km,2,2    
2015-01-22T07:37:30,1600,11 km,3,3    
2015-01-22T07:38:30,1700,12 km,4,4
```

sorry, im new to this site.

```
cat test1.log    
2015-01-22T07:36:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[     
Number of C is 1500    
Total distance 10 km    
Total number of A is 2    
Number of B is 2
]
--
2015-01-22T07:37:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[     
Number of C is 1600    
Total distance 11 km    
Total number of A is 3    
Number of B is 3    
]    
--    
2015-01-22T07:38:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[     
Number of C is 1700    
Total distance 12 km    
Total number of A is 4    
Number of B is 4    
]
```

**Re-attempt:**

```
    # awk -v RS='\n' -v OFS=, '$1~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T/ {if (s) print s; s=$1; next}
   /Total distance/{s = s OFS $(NF-1) " " $NF;next}
   NF>2{s = s OFS $NF}
   END{print s
}' test1.log
```

**Output**

,:[,1500,10 km,2,2,:[,1600,11 km,3,3,:[,1700,12 km,4,4

**Check***

```
# head -1 test.log|cat -vte
2015-01-22T07:36:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk on your given outpur:

```
awk -v RS='\r' -v OFS=, '$1~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T/ {if (s) print s; s=$1; next}
   /Total distance/{s = s OFS $(NF-1) " " $NF;next}
   NF>2{s = s OFS $NF}
   END{print s
}' file
2015-01-22T07:36:30,1500,10 km,2,2
2015-01-22T07:37:30,1600,11 km,3,3
2015-01-22T07:38:30,1700,12 km,4,4
```

Comment: timestamp is not printed. ,1500,10 km,2,2,1600,11 km,3,3,1700,12 km,4,4

Comment: Doesn't `2015-01-22T07:36:30` include timestamp as well. See attached output also

Comment: cat test1.log
2015-01-22T07:36:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ Number of C is 1500
Total distance 10 km
Total number of A is 2
Number of B is 2
]
--
2015-01-22T07:37:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ Number of C is 1600
Total distance 11 km
Total number of A is 3
Number of B is 3
]
--
2015-01-22T07:38:30 | 9316 | 461 | 50 | Messages from Summary report is :[ Number of C is 1700
Total distance 12 km
Total number of A is 4
Number of B is 4
]
,1500,10 km,2,2,1600,11 km,3,3,1700,12 km,4,4

Comment: As you can see no one can read any code or data from comments. Whatever you want to add, you can do so by editing your question. (Click edit button below your question)

Comment: I have modified answer slightly. Try updated code (you had `\r` in each line before `\n`)

Comment: my mistake, i have given return(\r) while edit text.  i have corrected the question. Appreciate your time in solving this

Comment: no, i have updated the re-attempt output above. tried with both '\r' and '\n'.

Comment: Instead of `-v RS='\n'` you need to have `-v RS='\r|\n'` and it is working fine for me with your new output as well. Tell me your awk version also

Comment: its same output. version: GNU Awk 3.1.7.  System details: Linux system01 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: gnu awk worked pretty well for me. Tell me output of `head -1 test.log|cat -vte`

Comment: i tried on local cygwin running 4.1.1 and the command works fine, however i have to run this command on awk 3.1.7 where application is running.    output - updated in above in question (Check)

Comment: If it works for you on cygwin and works for me on 2 different awk versions then command is right. You will have to check log file to make sure there is no special control character anywhere.

Comment: sure, i'll check and see if i can upgrade awk version on server.  Thanks for your time.